# Questions about HLSL Semantics

Tags: directx-12

I want to define the vertex struct like this:

```
struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL    : POSITION;
    float3 NormalL : NORMAL;
    float2 TexC    : TEXCOORD;
    float SH[9]; // ?
};
```

How to choose the vertex semantics of the 'SH' array? Can i define a semantic by myself?

Then I tried this:

```
// in hlsl:
struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL    : POSITION;
    float3 NormalL : NORMAL;
    float2 TexC    : TEXCOORD;
    float SH[9] : SHCOEFFICIENT; // ???
};

// cpp:
mInputLayout =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "SHCOEFFICIENT", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0, 32, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}, // ???
};
```

Of course, it's wrong.
So I split the array into 9 elements temporarily, but it looks stupid.

Comment: Yes, you can define it by yourself, but then you specify it in D3D12_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC too

Comment: I see, but there isn't a type of DXGI_FORMAT for array.Do you have some ideas to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SemanticIndex` parameter. You could define your input layout

```
mInputLayout =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "SHCOEFFICIENT", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0, 32, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    { "SHCOEFFICIENT", 1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0, 36, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    { "SHCOEFFICIENT", 2, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0, 40, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    ...
    { "SHCOEFFICIENT", 8, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0, 64, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
};
```

Or like this:

```
mInputLayout =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "SHCOEFFICIENT", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 32, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    { "SHCOEFFICIENT", 1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 44, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    { "SHCOEFFICIENT", 2, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 56, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
};
```

but change your vertex

```
struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL    : POSITION;
    float3 NormalL : NORMAL;
    float2 TexC    : TEXCOORD;
    float3 SH[3]   : SHCOEFFICIENT; 
};
```